# 16 TB what filesystem I should use

Tags: filesystem, raid

I need a 16 TB volume by 6 drives x 4TB. I use the last version of ubuntu. I need the filsytem very stable. How I can created this volume. I should use ext4, xfs, zfs, btrfs, with mdadm ?

Thanks a lot.

Edit

I don't need compatibility with OSX and windows. This drive I will use for backups, I will use freefilesync or unison. I need standard permissions. I quite nervous to use "news" filesytems.
 The filesytem it might store small|large files, such a .txt or ISO with some TB.
Thanks

Comment: the answer to this question would depend on how you plan to use the filesystems.  I.E. do you need windows or OSX to be able to read the drives or just LInux.  Do you need the fs to support linux type permissions, are you planning on using them for full `rsync` operations..... some fs's will support some of those but none of them will support all(afaik).  The size of the drive has more to do with what partition table you need to use, the filesystem itself is (mostly)agnostic as to drive/partition size(think you will need to use gpt tables for this size of a drive)

Comment: What research have you done? If I say "use filesystem xyz" how will you know I'm right?

Comment: To me this is a matter of opinion. I can make a case for ext4 but also for btfrs. When you are ONLY using it for BACKUPS I doubt it really even matters what the filesystem is.

Comment: not all fs types need md.  for example i have used btrfs spanned over 6 1TB volumes in AWS EC2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using btrfs with raid6. You do not need anything else.
So if for example you have sda,b,c,d,e,f and each have one partition:

```
mkfs.btrfs /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1
mkfs.btrfs -f -d raid6 -m raid6 -L 'writeyourlable' /dev/sd[a,b,c,d,e,f]1
mount -L 'writeyourlable' /whereever/you/want
```

Documentation is a bit sparse but that will give exactly 16TB with 2 drives fault tolerance.

Also, btrfs has other usefull features like snapshots and subvolumes that you might need with a 16 TB virtual drive.

Comment: Thanks. It's btrfs raid stable? I read many comments saying that it's stable\no stable. The device it must be very stable. The the filesytem it might store small|large files, such a .txt or ISO with some TB.

Comment: It is stable enough for facebook :D (zack loves it)

Comment: Thanks ;). Two more question, what flag I must choise partition (sda1...6), (linux, raid-auto). The last if I reinstall ubuntu, it auto detect the volume?

Comment: About the reinstall, yes it will be auto detected. About the flag, in which command it is asked? Also if an answer helped you, please accept it and upvote it :) .

Comment: I'm sorry Νίκος Φυτίλης, for now I don't have sufficient reputation. :( I'm collaborated in the forum, when I have sufficient reputation +1 . fdisk is the command that you can choose to elect the type of partition.  One more question in the past I used btrfs, but there are a slow boot, about +20 sec. Now there are the same problem? Thanks

Comment: raid6 is by definition slow. you may also need to fiddle with the kernel hooks to boot ubuntu from a btrfs partition, but i am not sure as i currently can not test that (but that is the case in arch linux that i currently use). You also probably can ignore setting the partition type through fdisk (i believe mkfs does that anyways)

Answer (score -1):

I don't need compatibility with OSX and windows. This drive I will use for backups, I will use freefilesync or unison. I need standard permissions. I quite nervous to use "news" filesytems.

Thanks

Comment: please *only* edit your question to add more info to your question. please do not post an answer that is not.

Comment: he did that 7 minutes ago ;)